# Can't found OCI.dll when PHP.exe try to execute on WinXp

Tags: php, dll

Try to install Composer for Laravel installation.

While it analyze `php.exe` it shows a message that it can't find `OCI.dll`. I try download `OCI.dll`, but get message that can't find in this dll some method.

How Can I fix it?

Comment: I solve It! in Php.ini comment all OCI8 module string. Thanks to all)

Answer (score 2):

Removing all oci extensions from php.ini solved my problem may be it helps.